# How to linearize the multiplication of variables and transform this into an MILP?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, linearization, convex-optimization, nonconvex-programming

Let $C=10$, $U=50$

$P_c,c=1,\cdots,C$ and $\alpha_{u,c},u=1,\cdots,U,c=1,\cdots,C$ are optimization variables

$\alpha_{u,c}$ is binary

$\sigma_{u,c}$, $d_{u,c}$ are known parameters

$\min \sum_{c=1}^CP_c$

$\gamma_u=\frac{\sum_{c=1}^C\alpha_{u,c}P_cd_{u,c}^{-3.76}}{\sum_{c=1}^C(1-\alpha_{u,c})P_cd_{u,c}^{-3.76}}$

$\gamma_u \ge \gamma_{th},\forall u$

$0\le P_c\le 100$

We have multiplication of vatiables, i.e., $\alpha_{u,c}P_c$ (in numerator) and $(1-\alpha_{u,c})P_c$ (in denominator)

How can I make this problem MILP?

Answer (score 1):

Numerator and denominator you'd rearrange as $ A \times d = n$ where $n,d$ are expressions of numerator & denominator.
As for multiplication of a binary variable $x$ with a continuous variable $p$ you can use the following constraints

$ xp_l \le \delta \le xp_u$

$ p - p_l(1-x) \le \delta \le p + p_u(1-x)$

where $ \delta$ is variable of same type as $p$ and $p_l,p_u$ are lower/upper bounds for $p$

Comment: would you tell more about the rearrangement

Comment: @KGM $ {n \over d} \ge \gamma_{th}$ transform to $ d\gamma_{th} \le n$